# How to Center a Popup Control on a Page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, popup

I have the following `Popup` that I am using which is by default in the upper left hand corner of the screen. I would like to be able to center this within my view so that I can stretch it to the width and height of the screen as well and change the opacity. I would like the user to be able to see what is behind the popup when it is displayed on the screen, but have the popup cover everything as well. What I have so far is as follows

```
<Grid x:Name="filterGrid">
                <Popup x:Name="trialPopup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.5">
                    <Border Margin="3" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">
                            <StackPanel Background="#FF1BA1E2">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="modeTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Do you wish to purchase the application?" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Grid Margin="0,10" >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Button x:Name="purchaseButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="purchase" Click="popupButton_Click"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="cancelButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="cancel" Click="popupButton_Click"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
```

Whenever I try to set `Width="Center"` and `Height="Center"` within the `Popup` element like the following

```
<Popup x:Name="trialPopup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

The top left corner is what is centered, and so the popup is not centered in the middle of the control itself. Is there a way to calculate the proper dimensions based on the popup width and height as well as the page width and height and apply this accordingly? Or is there a way to do this correctly within XAML? Also, the Opacity value is not being set?

Answer (score 1):

Center of Page:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" Placement="Center" />
```

Center of Window:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Placement="Center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Offset properties of Popup:

```
trialPopup.VerticalOffset = - ((FrameworkElement)trialPopup.Child).ActualHeight / 2;
trialPopup.HorizontalOffset = -((FrameworkElement)trialPopup.Child).ActualWidth / 2;
```

The Opacity will work when set for the Popup.Child, but I don't know why it won't work on Popup.